# ERROR: the "MEQP2" coding standard is not installed

Tags: magento2, meqp2

I am working on a module for magento 2.x, I need to validate the code of this for which install the following module Magento Extension Quality Program Coding Standard  but trying to use it generates this error some idea.

**ERROR: the "MEQP2" coding standard is not installed.**

Comment: Check : i think you will get help from this https://github.com/magento/marketplace-eqp/issues/50

Comment: Which IDE you are using

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
composer require --dev magento/magento-coding-standard

vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set installed_paths ../../magento/magento-coding-standard/
```

source https://github.com/magento/magento-coding-standard